# Toggle button to switch between desktop/mobile view like chrome desktop site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, viewport

For my mobile menu, I would like to add a toggle button to the desktop view, and the user can click the button again to go back to mobile view.

So far, I manage to make the button go to desktop view, but :-

1) **How can I toggle it back to mobile view?**
2) While in desktop view, if I go to other page, it just goes back to mobile view. **So, how can I force it based on my current preferred view?**

Basically, what I'm trying to achieve is exactly as chrome desktop site option.

Here's my code so far:

HTML

```
<button onclick="requestDesktopSite()">Request Desktop Site</button>
```

Javascript

```
function requestDesktopSite() {
document.getElementsByTagName('meta')['viewport'].content='width= 1440px;';
}
```

Comment: use cookies (javascript can store cookies too). Then in your page read the cookie and switch the view automaticaly. Then once user selects a differernt view, store it in cookie and swicth. This way you can keep the view between different page loads

Comment: like @NikosM. said - You need to store the information somewhere, so that your users client, remembers the selection

Comment: Alright. I'll look into storing cookies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe try this:

```
function requestDesktopSite(){
 if(document.getElementsByTagName('meta')['viewport'].content=='width= 1440px;'){
  document.getElementsByTagName('meta')['viewport'].content='width= 400px;';
 }else{
  document.getElementsByTagName('meta')['viewport'].content='width= 1440px;';
 }
}
```

Comment: geez why I don't even thought of this simple if statement.. Thank you!

Comment: @NazrinNoorzan no problem, can you accept the answer. thank you

Comment: yeah later. I'm looking into the cookies first.